# VirtualBox: ifconfig does not show my ip address

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos, bridge

I recently installed centos7 onto virtualbox. I enabled bridged networking on adapter 1 (enp0s3) on the virtualbox manager, to bridge my wireless adapter on the host.

When I type `ifconfig` on the guest (the VM), I can't see any ip address, and can't access the internet.

[image: ifconfig]

Later, I changed the bridged adapter to adapter 3 and then I see an ip address under enp0s3. What gives?

Can someone explain to be the difference between choosing Adapter #'s 1,2,3, and 4? Also, is enp0s3 the adapter I should use? or the third one, virbr0 (not sure what this is)? My guess is the loopback adapter isn't right.

Comment: Depending on how much magic VirtualBox performs, bridging to a wireless adapter is not possible, because it’s a point-to-point connection that doesn’t expect a network on the client end.

Answer (score 1):

After udev-200, the naming convention of interfaces no longer follows the kernel naming convention. Hence, eth0 no longer exists and something like enp0s3 is the new naming convention. Now the name differ depending on where the ethernet card is on the board.

There is no difference between the adapter number, but there might be a difference if the **Attached to** is different. Make sure you are using the correct form of attachment to your **Host**.

virbr0 is a virtual network interface that is used to connect the **Host** to the **Guest** in a virtualized environment. You don't really have to worry about it now.

The loopback adapter looks fine.

Comment: if adapter 1,2,3,4 does not matter, how does VirtualBox know which adapter on the VM side to bridge? e.g. enp0s3 vs. virbr0.

Comment: Virbr0 will not work unless it is configured to but enp0s3 might differ if you change adapter. Forget about virbr0.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the enp0s3 adapter. Edit/create `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3` as root and you can set an IP, DNS  gateway, set on boot and other options. Then reboot and you should have internet. You also want to run `echo "<IP of DNS server>" >> /etc/resolv.conf` to set a DNS server if it isn't specified in `ifcfg-enp0s3`.

You can use this as a template: https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/2172388

The part of the `UUID`, use `uuidgen enp0s3` and copy the output and use it for the `ifcfg-enp0s3`.

Comment: Actually, before you continue with my answer, how are your network adapters set up in the vm settings?

Comment: This will only work if your `enp0s3` is bridged to your external network.

Comment: Right now it is on VirtualBox: Adapter 2, Bridged Adapter, Wireless LAN PCI (the right one I use on my host), Deny promiscuous mode, and cable connected.

Comment: Nah, just edit the IP, DNS1, GATEWAY, subnet mask. That should get you online.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command, it should fix the issue.

nmcli connection up enp0s3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).